# .net dropdownlist if condition

Tags: vb.net, datetime, drop-down-menu

I had posted this question before but didn't get the right answer -
here's my code again with the if condition.

```
Dim provider As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture 
Dim a1 As DateTime = Nothing 
If date1.selectedvalue isnot nothing Then
    insexp = DateTime.ParseExact(date1.SelectedValue, "MMMM yyyy", provider) 
End If
If a1.Month = Today.Month AndAlso a1.Year = Today.Year Then 
    a1 = Today.Date 
End If
```

date1 is a dropdownlist in the aspx page and does not have a value if you don't select it. Its not a mandatory dropdownlist. When i run it in debugger mode I get the value of `date1 = ""`. And that goes into the if condition and crashes. Please advice how to make this IF condition work

Answer (score 2):

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(date1.sSelectedValue) Then
    insexp = DateTime.ParseExact(date1.SelectedValue, "MMMM yyyy", provider) 
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Check selectedindex instead of selectedvalue